# ns2 cannot connect to existing nam instance

Tags: tcl, ns2, nam

I'm trying to run the below code using nam.

```
set ns [new Simulator]

set nf [open lab1.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf

set f [open lab1.tr w]

proc record {} {

global sink f
set ns [Simulator instance]

set time 0.12

set bw [$sink set bytes_]

set now [$ns now]

puts $f "$now [expr (($bw/$time)*8/1000000)]"

$sink set bytes_ 0

$ns at [expr $now+$time] "record"
}


proc finish {} {
    global ns nf f
    $ns flush-trace
    close $nf
    close $f
    exit 0
}


set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]

$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 4Mb 10ms DropTail


set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
$udp0 set packetSize_ 1500
$ns  attach-agent $n0 $udp0

set traffic0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]

$traffic0 set packetsize_ 1500
$traffic0 set interval_ 0.01
$traffic0 attach-agent $udp0

set sink [new Agent/LossMonitor]
$ns attach-agent $n1 $sink

$ns connect $udp0 $sink


$ns at 0.0 "record"
$ns at 2.0 "$traffic0 start"
$ns at 10.0 "$traffic0 stop"

$ns at 12.0 "finish"
$ns run
```

I'm trying to run it on a Virtual Machine using VirtualBox with windows 7 32bit.

On cmd first i execute the command `ns lab1.tcl`
After this im trying to open nam , using the command `nam lab1.nam`.
When i do this, i get the message

[image]

Nam is actually then running but not properly,meaning it always creates packets of 210 bytes and my code doesn't affect this whatever packetsize i give.

Comment: Looks like an unterminated string, and that is probably in the command line parsing. Which is very odd indeed, as that is a well-tested part of most runtimes on Windows. I'm guessing the code was built with one runtime and is executing with another! Everything is easier on other platforms, where runtimes are quite a lot simpler...

Answer (score 0):

> cannot connect to existing nam instance

Not an error. Nam will show that message any time, when no nam window is present.

My test : `$ ns235-64-orig user7375077.tcl` ... Result : lab1.nam 288.5kB,  lab1.tr 3.3kB .

`$ nam lab1.nam` : OK ...

[image]

A stock ns-2.35 was used. No patching. .... May be you added some changes which can make nam work poorly ? ( Or may be it is the Cygwin created nam being corrupt ? )

Suggestions : Make your "ns2 work" with a genuine Linux OS. Easy install : 1) Install 'VirtualBox'. 2) Install the Linux OS(´s) into VirtualBox. The safe OS choice : Redhat CentOS 6.8 http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/centos.org/6.8/isos/x86_64/CentOS-6.8-x86_64-LiveCD.iso