# Explain network congestion and packet loss using NS, NAM and XGRAPH

Tags: networking, packet, ns2, nam

I have created in NS two nodes connected over a 4Mbps connection with a delay of 10ms.

Node1 is a transmitter and Node2 is a receiver.

The transmitter node sends packets at a rate of 10ms (0.01s).

Packet transmission starts at 2s in the simulation.

Considering the above, as long as my packets are < 5000 bytes in size I am below the 4Mbps limit of the connection.

What I am trying to understand is what happens when I increase packet size beyond 5000 bytes.

So, if i increase packet size to 8000 bytes here is what happens, using NAM for the animation

[image]

The first packet is sent at 2s and the second is sent at 2.016s. Note that a packet is sent every 0.01s, so the 2nd packet should have been sent at 2.01s. Also notice that we are currently at 2.02+ seconds in the simulation, so the third packet should have already left Node1.

NAM's documentation says that

> Queued packets are shown as little squares.[...] Dropped packets are shown as falling rotating squares, and disappear at the end of the screen.

So I am not having any dropped packets?

Using XGRAPH for the simulation we get this graph

[image]

Now, I can't quite understand the following:

- What is the relation between the packet arrows length and the connection?
- What does the fact that packet transmission does not happen at the set interval of 10ms mean?
- What does the fact that I am pushing a transmission rate above 4Mbps mean for a connection limited to 4Mbps?
- Why, in the graph, I see spikes and why do they go beyond 4Mbps?

UPDATE: Added the `.tcl` script

```
set ns [new Simulator]

set nf [open lab1.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf

set xf [open lab1.tr w]

proc record {} {
     global sink xf
     set ns [Simulator instance]

     set time 0.12

     set bw [$sink set bytes_]

     set now [$ns now]

     puts $xf "$now [expr ((($bw/$time)*8)/1000000)]"

     $sink set bytes_ 0

     $ns at [expr $now+$time] "record"
}
proc finish {} {
  global ns nf xf
  $ns flush-trace
  close $nf
  close $xf
  exit 0
}
set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 4Mb 10ms DropTail

set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
$udp0 set packetSize_ 1500
$ns attach-agent $n0 $udp0

set traffic0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]

$traffic0 set packetSize_ 1500
$traffic0 set interval_ 0.01
$traffic0 attach-agent $udp0

set sink [new Agent/LossMonitor]
$ns attach-agent $n1 $sink

$ns connect $udp0 $sink
$ns at 0.0 "record"
$ns at 2.0 "$traffic0 start"
$ns at 10.0 "$traffic0 stop"
$ns at 12.0 "finish"
$ns run
```

UPDATE2:

Dropped packets begin to show in the simulation animation after some time passes and not immediately, it turns out. So for example I'll have to run the simulation for about 3-4 seconds before dropped packets begin to show.

Comment: About your xgraph image : Looks like it's created from an ordinary trace file. Please read "VIII. Creating Output Files for Xgraph" http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript4.html ... Examples : xgraph_ns2-files-tcl_07.2016.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNWEJCa1QxN284bUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean 'it was created from an ordinary trace file" The trace file was created from my `.tcl` script of the simulation. Updated the question with the code if it helps

Comment: ? Did you read the other threads with the same file.tcl, and the same issues ? 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998726/ns2-cannot-connect-to-existing-nam-instance  2) http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/xgraph-problem-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-4175602399/#3

Comment: @KnudLarsen did you read my question before commenting with "same issues" links?

Comment: I am commenting on the image only.

Comment: One information is missing : Your OS → Name and version. I couldn't reproduce your spikes, any Linux OS. Except for a lookalike image : With an LTE patched ns2.

Comment: @KnudLarsen OS is WIn10x64 (running in VM). Anyway, do not bother too much with this.